# Python, Searching in a list of lists for the index of the nearest match from a given coordinate

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a list of lists with the following values:

```
field = [[0,  0,  0, -1,  0, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0],
     [0, -1,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0, -1,  0,  0],
     [0,  0,  0,  0, -1, 0, 0,  0, -1,  0],
     [0,  0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0],
     [0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0,  0, -1, -1]]
```

I need to find the the nearest value -1 from a given coordinate

I managed to get the index for all matches

My code so far:

```
x = 0
y = 4
value = -1
coordinates = field[x][y]

for i, row in enumerate(field):
    for j, elem in enumerate(row):
        if elem == value:
           print(i,j)
```

So for example if the coordinates given are (0,4) it should return the coordinates (1,7) witch matches the nearest value(-1)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why should (2,1) match to (2,4)? Isn't (1,1) nearer?

Comment: can you explain the pattern more clear ? i didnt understand

Comment: if x=0, y=4 should it return (1,1) or (1,7)?

Comment: Edited the post for better clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
field = [[0,  0,  0, -1,  0, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0],
     [0, -1,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0, -1,  0,  0],
     [0,  0,  0,  0, -1, 0, 0,  0, -1,  0],
     [0,  0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0],
     [0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0,  0, -1, -1]]

x = 2
y = 1
z = -1

def coords(field, x,y,z):
    for i, row in enumerate(field[x:]):
        for j, elem in enumerate(row):
            if elem == z and j > y:
                return i+x,j
coords(field,x,y,z)
```

Output

```
(2, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for j, elem in enumerate(field[x][y:]):
    if elem == z:
           print(i,j)
           return
for i, row in enumerate(field[x+1:]):
    for j, elem in enumerate(row):
        if elem == z:
           print(i,j)
           return
```